# Add additional syntax highlighter plugin to PrismJS in HCL Connections 6.5 CR1 TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, ibm-connections, prismjs, hcl-connections

I installed the [TinyMCE editor](https://help.hcltechsw.com/connections/v65/admin/install/tiny_editors/c_tiny-editors.html) on top of a fresh Connections 6.5.1 installation. While syntax highlighting using the [codesample plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/codesample/) is enabled out of the box, it works only for certain languages. I found the `codesample_languages`, which were [overriden like described in this article](https://u-labs.de/portal/konfiguration-von-standard-plugins-in-tinymce-auf-connections-6-aendern/).

```
externalPlugins: [{
      name: "codesample",
      url: "/connections/resources/web/tiny.editors.connections/tinymce/plugins/codesample/plugin.min.js",
      settings: {
        codesample_global_prismjs: true,
        codesample_languages: [
          { text: 'ASP.NET (Core)', value: 'aspnet' },
          { text: 'Apache', value: 'apacheconf' },
          { text: 'Bash', value: 'bash' },
          { text: 'C#', value: 'csharp' },
          { text: 'C++', value: 'cpp' },
          { text: 'CSS', value: 'css' }
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

Now its possible to select them in the editor. But they don't work because the embedded PrismJS from the editor only support `extend, insertBefore, DFS, markup, xml, html, mathml, svg, css, clike, javascript, js, c, csharp, cs, dotnet, cpp, java, markup-templating, php, python, py, ruby, rb`.

So I loaded the missing plugins from a cdn, e.g. the [batch plugin](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/prismjs@1.18.0/components/prism-bash.js). Including it in `header.jsp` doesn't work because the `Prism` namespace is not initialized. In the `footer.jsp` it seems to have no effect, assuming that PrismJS is already initialized.

### Customizing the webresource archive

PrismJS seems to be fetched from `https://cnx65.internal/connections/resources/web/tiny.editors.connections/render/prism.js` so I extracted `tiny.editors.connections_4.2.1.1.jar` in `/opt/IBM/shared/provision/webresources`, modified `resources/render/prism.js` and re-packed those folter:

```
[centos@cnx65 webresources]$ zip -r tiny.editors.connections_4.2.1.1.jar resources/render/
```

After restarting Common and Wiki (the application where I'm testing TinyMCE), there is still no syntax highlighting for Bash. Altough when I'm navigating to `https://cnx65.internal/connections/resources/web/tiny.editors.connections/render/prism.js`, I see the Bash plugin code which I have inserted. To see which languages are avaliable, I append

```
console.log(Object.keys(Prism.languages))
```

at the end of the file. This gave me an array containing `bash`. So the plugin is avaliable, but why doesn't TinyMCE show syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

PrismJS was not the problem: Connections changed the way how they use PrismJS. In the past, they just append the class so that we need to include prisms css/js files in the rendered page (e.g. header/footer.jsp). But it seems that since 6.5.1 (CR1), the TinyMCE editor calls PrismJS when a code block is changed. After pressing *save*, the editor places the entire parsed highlighted HTML with inline css in its HTML.

As a consequence, it's not enough to reload the rendered page in read mode because it was rendered *before* the lighlight plugin was added. The highlighting works when we click on *edit* and make a double click in the code block. Then click *save* in the code modal and also in the wiki page. Now it works:

[image: Working highlighting]

### Highlight in the editor, too

I found out that `resources/render/prism.js` is responsible for the readonly view, but not the editor itself. If we only add the plugin there, we get no highlighting in the edit view

[image: Editor highlighting not working]

To fix this, we need to edit `resources/tinymce/tinymce-bundle.min.js` inside the TinyMCE archive. Add the plugin JS code in the plugins section. For example, before `Prism.languages.csharp=...`. Now add the modified file to the archive

```
[centos@cnx65 webresources]$ sudo zip -r tiny.editors.connections_4.2.1.1.jar resources/tinymce/tinymce-bundle.min.js
```

and restart common + the application you're using (e.g. Wikis). Now the highlighting works both in the readonly view as well inside the editor:

[image]